# Integrate problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

We have to integrate $\int _0^{\pi }\:\left|\sin\left(2x\right)\right|dx$ and in my book, they split integral:  $\int _0^{\pi }\:\left|\sin\left(2x\right)\right|dx=\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:\sin\left(2x\right)dx-\int _{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\pi }\:\sin\left(2x\right)dx$ and I don't understand why they split because between $\left[0,\pi \right]$ sinus is positive, for example: $\int _0^{\pi }\:\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|dx=\int _0^{\pi }\:\sin\left(x\right)dx$. Why $\int _0^{\pi }\:\left|\sin\left(2x\right)\right|dx$ is not equal with $\int _0^{\pi }\:\sin\left(2x\right)dx$ ?

Without graph, can someone show me how can I realize where the function is negative or positive?

Comment: $\sin(\color{red}{2}x)$ is positive for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$ and negative for $x\in(\pi/2,\pi)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio how can I prove sin(2x) is negative on pi/2 and pi?

Comment: $\sin(2x)$ over $[\pi/2,\pi]$ takes the same values of $\sin(x)$ over $[\pi,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the plot you can know why:  the function changes its sign at $\pi/2$

[image]

Comment: thanks, but if I don't know the graph in another situation, how can I realize where is positive and where is negative without graph ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sin{(2x)}$ is periodic on $[0, \pi]$ since its input $x$ is being doubled. So $\sin{(2x)} < 0$ when $\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \pi$.

Comment: how can I prove sin(2x) is negative on pi/2 and pi?

Comment: since $sin(x) < 0$ from $\pi < x< 2\pi$ then $sin(2x) < 0$ for $\pi < 2x < 2\pi$ which implies $\frac{\pi}{2} < x< \pi$

Comment: okay, I understand.. but suppose we don't know neither sign of sin(x), how we can find where is negative sin(x) ?

Answer (score 1):

But the function you consider is not sin(x), it is sin(2x). So sin(2x) is positive where inside of it between (0,pi) so x is between (0,pi/2).

Comment: how can I prove sin(2x) is negative on pi/2 and pi?

Comment: change variables say 2x = u, then sin(u) < 0, it means   pi<u<2pi, then pi<2x<2pi, then pi/2<x<pi. If you dont know neither sign of sin(x), plot unit circle and y axis is sin axis so sinx is negative under orijin, correspondant angle from +x axis is greater than 180 and less than 360 which gives same result.